# Why StateNotifierProvider not update state in UI

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm currently developing Android/iOS apps using [flutter_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod).
And I'm trying to redraw the UI using `StateNotifierProvider`.
However, although the state should have been updated, only the UI is not updated.

### My `StateNotifierProvider` code

Here, user information is managed by `StateNotifierProvider`.

```
final myProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<MyProvider, MyData>(
        (ref) => MyProvider(MyData()));

class MyData {
  bool myBool = false;
  String? text;
}

class MyProvider extends StateNotifier<MyData> {
  MyProvider(super.state);

  Future<void> update(){
    state.myBool = true;
  }
}
```

### My `ref.read` code

This is called when the user presses a particular button.

```
void onTapButton() {
  ref.read(myProvider).update();
}
```

### My UI code

Here I'm showing a simple UI that shows what's going on with `myBool` in `MyData`.
But display `false` after pushed button `onTapButton()`.

```
class Main extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  build (context, ref) {

    bool b = ref.watch(myProvider).myBool;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(b.toString()), // always false...
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I redraw the screen using hot reload, the UI will be updated to show `true`.

Comment: Just a note, since you're using StateNotifierProvider: The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Answer (score 0):

StateNotifier need use the setter method `state = MyData()` to notifier to listeners

```
class MyProvider extends StateNotifier<MyData> {
  MyProvider(super.state);

  Future<void> update(){
    final previousState = state;
    state = MyData()..text = previousState.text..myBool=true;
  }
}
```

Consider implementing `copyWith` function for your `MyData` so you don't need to do `final previousState = state;` like my example. And the state (`MyData`) should be immutable.

See [StateNotifierProvider](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/state_notifier_provider) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with freezed package.